# Number sorter program with cannot find symbol compilation error

Tags: java, arraylist

I am attempting to create a number sorter program where the user enters 10 numbers and then they are put into three separate array lists, a list with odd, even, and negative numbers. But, when I run the program it tells me: "cannot find symbol
symbol  : method add(int)"

This is when I am attempting to put the positive numbers into an array list. How do I solve this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NumberSorter
{
public static void main(String [] args)
 {
  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
  Number[]numbers = new Number[10];
  Number[]oddList = new Number[10];
  Number[]evenList = new Number[10];
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
  {
   System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
   numbers[i] = reader.nextDouble();
   if (i % 2 == 0)
    evenList.add(i);
   return evenList;
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: You're not trying to do anything with `ArrayList`. You never mention `ArrayList` other than in the import. You're dealing with arrays, which don't have an `add` method.

Comment: There are no methods on arrays, they are essentially primitives (even if they aren't fully). You can assign values to array objects by `evenList[listIndex] = i`. You will need to keep a separate index for `evenList` if you do not want holes.

Answer (score 1):

So something like this?

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NumberSorter
{
public static void main(String [] args)
 {
  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
  Number[]numbers = new Number[10];
  ArrayList<Number>oddList = new ArrayList<Number>();
  ArrayList<Number>evenList = new ArrayList<Number>();
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
  {
   System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
   numbers[i] = reader.nextDouble();
   if (numbers[i].intValue() % 2 == 0)
   {
       evenList.add(numbers[i]);
   } else {
       oddList.add(numbers[i]);
   }
   }
  }
 }
```

To print it out the list you can add the following to the end:

```
for (Number num : oddList) {
      System.out.println("oddlist: " + num );
  }

  for (Number num : evenList) {
      System.out.println("evenlist: " + num );
  }
```

EDIT-Using arrays only

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberSorter
{
public static void main(String [] args)
 {  
  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
  Number[]numbers = new Number[10];
  Number[] oddList = new Number[10];
  Number[] evenList = new Number[10];
  int oddListIndex = 0;
  int evenListIndex = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
  {
   System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
   numbers[i] = reader.nextDouble();
   if (numbers[i].intValue() % 2 == 0)
   {
       evenList[evenListIndex]=numbers[i];
       evenListIndex++;
   } else {
       oddList[oddListIndex]=numbers[i];
       oddListIndex++;
   }
   }
  System.out.println("evenlist:");
   for( int i = 0; i < evenListIndex; i++) {
       System.out.println(evenList[i]);
   }
  System.out.println("oddlist:");
   for( int i = 0; i < oddListIndex; i++) {
       System.out.println(oddList[i]);
   }

  }
 }
```

Comment: I am trying to do that except using arrays not an array list. Is that similar?

Comment: Arrays and arraylist are different. The most significant difference here is arraylist are able to grow any time where as the size of the array is set when it is instantiated. Let me update the code so it only uses array.

Answer (score 1):

public class SorterNumber {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Double> negative = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> odd = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> even = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
        Double x = reader.nextDouble();
        if (Math.signum(x) == -1) {
            negative.add(x);
        } else if (x % 2 == 0) {
            even.add(x);
        } else if (x % 2 != 0) {
            odd.add(x);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(negative);
    System.out.println(even);
    System.out.println(odd);
}
```

}